# I execute Promsie.all () in Promise's then () method, and the method in Promsie.all () is executed first. The code is as follows

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    const url="http://127.0.0.1/index.php?id=";
   let task = [];
   let task01 = function()
   {
        return new Promise( function(resolve , reject){
            $.ajax({
              url: url+1,
              context: document.body,
              success: function(){
                resolve('success');
                 console.log("01");
                }
           });
        })
   }
      task[0]= function(){
        new Promise( function(resolve , reject){
            $.ajax({
              url: url+2,
              context: document.body,
              success: function(){
                resolve('success');
                 console.log("02");
                }
           });
        })
      }


     task[1] = function(){
       new Promise( function(resolve , reject){
           $.ajax({
             url: url+3,
             context: document.body,
             success: function(){
               resolve('success');
                console.log("03");
               }
          });
       })
     }


    task01().then(function(value){
         Promise.all(task);
    })


</script>
```

I execute Promsie.all () in Promise's then () method, and the method in Promsie.all () is executed first. The code is as follows
Where did I go wrong ,my code result as follow the pictrue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYrxD.png)

Comment: No need to create new Promise since `$.ajax` returns promise. See:  [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: Also code shown never even calls the functions in task array and neither of those functions returns anything

Comment: "*the method in Promsie.all () is executed first*" - what method are you talking about? `task` is an array of functions, not a method, and none of them are executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your code, I do not think that the code in your `task` array functions is executed at all. `Promise.all` expects array /iterable object to be exact/ of promises but you are passing it just an array of functions, which are never going to be executed. In order, this example to work first your functions in your `task` array have to return promise, and second, you have to envoke those function. Something similar to:

```
task[0] = function() {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
    url: url + 2,
    context: document.body,
    success: function(){
      console.log('02');
      resolve('success');
    }
  });
});
```

};

```
task[1] = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $.ajax({
      url: url + 3,
      context: document.body,
      success: function(){
        console.log('03');
        resolve('success');
      }
    });
  });
};

task01().then(function(value) {
  const taskPromises = task.map((fn)=>fn());
  Promise.all(taskPromises);
});
```

As a side note your code is a bit messy, please try to write more clear code;

Comment: Good work! You're at the nub of the issue... Promise.all is not expecting an array of functions...